# Logarithm on $A(\overline{\mathbb{D}})$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disk and let $A(\mathbb{\overline{D}})$ be the space of functions which are continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$. 
I can prove by means of the holomorphic functional calculus for Banach algebras that any $f \in A(\overline{\mathbb{D}})$ which has no zeros admits a logarithm. However, this seems like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer, so the question is:
Does anyone know a more elementary proof of this fact?

I tried to use the fact that the set of $f \in A(\overline{\mathbb{D}})$ that are analytically continuable beyond $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is dense in $A(\overline{\mathbb{D}})$ but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\DC{\overline{\Bbb D}}$

Sledgehammer or not, are you sure your proof by the functional calculus is correct? 
I don't see how it can work; seems to me that to make any sort of functional-calculus argument work we need to know there exists $g$ at least continuous on $f(\DC)$ with $e^{g(z)}=z$, and that's simply not true (for exammple, $f(\DC)$ could be an annullus centered at the origin).

Since $\overline{\Bbb D}$ is simply connected there exists a *continuous* function $L:\overline{\Bbb D}\to\Bbb C$ with $$e^L=f.$$It's not hard to show that it follows that $L$ is holomorphic  in $\Bbb D$.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. You are indeed right that my functional calculus argument does not work. I was implicitly assuming that $f ( \mathbb{D})$ were simply connected.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Only now, I noticed that there is one point that I don't understand:
How do you conclude that $f$ has a _continuous_ logartithm? Can you give a reference for this fact? In my sources the notion of simple connectedness is only used for open sets.

Comment: @BrunoKrams Look at the proof in your sources for simply connected open sets; the same argument shows that if $X$ is any simply-connected topological  space and $f\in C(X)$ has no zero then $f$ has a continuous logarithm

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunatelly, the sources I know all deal with complex analysis. The proof always goes like "integrate $f' / f$ along some curve which connects some initial point $z_0$ with $z$." However, in my case $f' / f$ need not be integrable.

Comment: @BrunoKrams Ok, if they express it that way the proof doesn't generalize to general simply connected spaces; in that context there's  no such thing as $f'$. A standard reference would be Massey _Algebraic Topology_.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again